# How to get the value of a group of Radio Buttons in ReactJS

Tags: forms, reactjs

I have a group of 4 radio buttons and I need to get the value of the selected button. I should make sure that the user has selected one of the radio buttons. Here is how I'm trying to do it:

```
export const ReportClass = React.createClass({
    mixins: [React.addons.LinkedStateMixin],

    getInitialState() {
        return {
            reason: "",
        }
    },

    setError(id, msg) {
        const err = this.state.errors;
        err[id] = msg;
        this.setState({errors: this.state.errors});
    },

    sendReport(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(this.state.reason);
        console.log(this.state.reason.value);
        if (!this.state.reason) {
           this.setError('reason', "Please choose one");
           return;
        }
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <form className="form-h" onSubmit={this.sendReport}>                        
                    <label forHtml='first'> first radio button </label> 
                    <input ref='first' name='reason' type='radio' value='first' checkedLink={this.linkState('reason')} />

                    <label forHtml='second'> second radio button </label>
                    <input ref='second' name='reason' type='radio' value='second' checkedLink={this.linkState('reason')} />

                    <label forHtml='third'> third radio button</label>
                    <input ref='third' name='reason' type='radio' value='third' checkedLink={this.linkState('reason')} />

                    <label forHtml='forth'> forth radio button </label>
                    <input ref='forth' name='reason' type='radio' value='forth' checkedLink={this.linkState('reason')} />

                    <div className="col-sm">
                        <button type="submit" className="btn" onClick={this.sendReport}> Send</button>
                    </div>                            
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

The `console.log(this.state.reason)` returns `true` when one of the buttons is selected and the second one, `console.log(this.state.reason.value)` returns `undefined`. So how can I get the value to know which one is chosed?

Comment: Is that what you expected? http://jsbin.com/gupatu/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Listen to checkbox changes event, then store the value, then retrieve this value on submit?

Comment: @MichaelRasoahaingo Yes that's what I want! Please post it as the answer :) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `checkedLink` binds checked-ness of an *individual* radio button to the state. Because you're binding multiple radio buttons to the same state key and radio buttons are mutually exclusive, the `reason` will always be whichever change event fired last.

In my opinion, the best solution is to use [`react-radio-group`](https://github.com/chenglou/react-radio-group).

If you don't want an external dependency, an easy alternative is to not link state at all and set an onChange handler on every radio button that looks like this:

```
function onChange(e) {
  if (e.target.selected) {
    this.setState({ reason: e.target.value });
  }
}
```

Now we don't need to worry about managing the checked-ness of each radio button, we just grab the reason whenever one is clicked. The downside to this is that it doesn't go both ways: if you *set* the reason on the state it wouldn't change which radio button is actually clicked.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's very helpful. and as you said, I prefer to avoid the dependencies.